# Display Width and height of device got changed on changing orientation for Finding aspect ratio of an android device

Tags: android

Hi i found issue regarding the pixels width and height calculation of tablet on changing orientation portrait where width =800 and height =1200 in landscape mode its changed to width=1165 and height =790 why this difference is coming 
i am using this code

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;`
```

Comment: This may be unrelated to your query but, to get display height and width I find it easier to simply use my views. For eg: if I know a particular view is taking up entire screen width, I simply call `getWidth()` on it. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible because your device hardware buttons also consumed some screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I would suppose it is because there are some constraints that are holding some space in landscape than in portrait.

Answer (score 0):

in your onConfigurationChanged get height and width of a view instead of device metrics

```
 final View view = findViewById(R.id.yourView);

    ViewTreeObserver observer = view.getViewTreeObserver();
    observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            Log.v(TAG,""+ view.getWidth()+" "+
                            view.getHeight());
            view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It could mean some things:

- The app has menu bar / status bar.
- The phone has button bar.

And some other things. ( For example a resize of the app )

To get the absolute phone's screen size, use this code:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
```

Thats it.